# JpaRepository save not returning the attributes of nested objects updated by id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a user being updated threw a patch request, and the client is allowed to send
a json request with and image id so i can assign if to the user

```
{"image": {"id": 3}}
```

while the full image object is like this

```
 "image": {
    "id": 3,
    "fileUrl": "/uploads/identity.jpg",
    "fileUrlType": "RELATIVE"
}
```

when I assign the id to new ImageEntity and set it to my user then call repository.save(updatedUser) it is saved correctly to the database with all its attributes.

**the problem is that the return of the save method is returning a user with an image with only an id attribute (other attributes are set to null)**

PS: when i try later to fetch the user from another request i find that it has all the images attributes that it needs

is there a way to make the repository?save(updatedUser) return the user. image with all its attributes?

i tried to call **saveAndFlush** instead of **save** but it did not work, I also tried to call getById(user. id) directly after the save and it didn't work either

this is my service code

```
    public User patchUser(User user, FullUserDto userDto) {
    userMapper.updateUserFromDto(userDto, user);
    return this.userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entity definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to change two things:

1. use `saveAndFlush(user)` instead of `save(user)`
2. call `entityManager.refresh(user)` after calling saveAndFlush

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by calling entityManager.refresh(user) after saving